How can i run a python script i made from replit.com in Windows Powershell or cmd prompt?
So I'm kinda new to programming and i went to replit.com made a python script following this video, but i seem to be stuck at 40:08, how do i run the script that i have from replit in windows powershell or cmd promt?
PS: my computer runs windows 7
I tried many websites trying to find an answer and even ChatGPT didn't help, and no one is answering me on reddit too. so i'm on here hoping that someone will help me out.

You'll need to install python in order to run... well, python :)

i downloaded python 3.6.2 and i pasted my codes from the replit to python, saved it into my folder. and added the folder that has the script i pasted and saved from python, pip3, python.exe etc etc... to path under environment variables but i still seem to be lost...

Simply execute python <path to the script file you want to execute> (without the angle brackets).

If you meant at replit's shell, i did that and typed "python (name).py" kept giving me errors and i fixed them very small ones until it tells me that theres an error at line 103, and line 103 is: "except Exception as e:". Line 104: "print(f'ERROR: {e}') i asked chatgpt but it kept telling me to type the "try:" command above but it made it worse. What did i do wrong?

yup installing python and adding it to path under environment variables should do it.

i downloaded python 3.6.2 and i pasted my codes from the replit to python, saved it into my folder. and added the folder that has the script i pasted and saved from python, pip3, python.exe etc etc... to path under environment variables but i still seem to be lost...

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

First install Python. It will let you install automatically the enviroment variable path. Then, in CMD or PS (preferably open as administrator) type python --version or python3 --version to see the installed python version. Now, move to your .py file directory and type python your_file.py or python3 your_file.py. Hope this can help you :)
About your code error, check that the try/except block is correctly formated in this way:
try:
   #stuf
except:
   #exception stuf

And not like this:
try:
   #stuf
  except:
   #except stuf

In your exception print, try this:
print(f'ERROR:' + e)


So i went on cmd,  and for some reason when i type "python --version" it doesn't work but when i type "py --version" it works. And i'm not sure if you meant typing "python my_script.py" at cmd, so i did that and it gave me an error about line 102, and line 102 says: "except Exception as e:" 103: "print(f'ERROR: {e}')". I don't understand what's wrong.

@UCL404 about the py --version command, it works due to how Python is installed on your system, so "py" is a launcher that comes with recent versions of Python on Windows. Yes! I meant to type the command python my_script.py but the error you are getting comes from your code. It would be nice if you edit your cuestion and add it to understand better and see what is wrong :)

Thanks for replying! About the errors, not the best idea but i went and asked chatGPT to look for any errors and they weren't so bad but it can't fix the one i mentioned. Do you have any idea what that could be?

@UCL404 have you ensure that both try and except blocks are indented at the same level? This is a common error that sometimes ChatGPT does not take into account

Do you mind giving me an example please?

@UCL404 sure! check my edited answer. I added another tip. Hope it would help you

Can i send a picture to you via social media? i really don't know how to explain this.

Sure! My IG profile is in my linktr.ee link as DevEzro. But also there's is no problem to share it here :)
